# Red Black Trees Rebalancing

Tags: algorithm, red-black-tree

I want to insert 7 items in my tree -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 and 3. I get a well balanced tree of height 3 without doing rotations when I insert by this order: 0, -2, 2, -1, 1, -3, 3. But when I insert all items in ascending order, the right part of the root node does rebalancing, but the left part of the the root node doesn't. All rebalancing algorithms I have seen, do rebalancing from the inserted node up to the root node, and then they stop. Shouldn't they continue to the opposite part of the root node? And I have the feeling it gets worse, if I insert lots of items in ascending order (like 0 to 100). At the end tree is balanced, but is not height optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the balanced binary-search trees (R/B trees, AVL trees, etc.) provide absolute balancing, that is none of them provide minimal possible height. This is because it is not possible to do such a "complete" rebalancing fast. If we want always to keep the height minimal possible, a heavy rebalancing will often be required on tree operations, and therefore the rebalancing will not work in `O(log N)`. As a result, all the operations (insert, update, delete, etc) will not work in `O(log N)` time also, and this will destroy the whole idea of balanced tree.

What balanced trees *do* guarantee is a not-so-strict requirement on tree height: the tree height is `O(log N)`, that is `C*log N` for some constant `C`. So the tree is not guaranteed to be ideally balanced, but the balance will always be not far from ideal.

Comment: I added 1000 items in ascending order, and I ended up with a height of 16! Seems pretty good even if tree isn't 100% balanced.