# Can hinted insert to std::map lead to unbalanced tree?

Tags: c++

Does this lead to unbalanced tree (and subsequent poor search performance) in `std::map/set`:

```
std::set<int> s;
for(int i = 0; i< 1000; ++i)
    s.insert(s.end(), i);
```

?

Or in other words: will "hinted insert" rebalance underlying tree as required?

Afaik, C++ standard does not guarantee this, but I wonder how most popular implementations behave in this case.

Comment: I think it will not, after all, the implementation is probably optimized to insert ordered sequences. Actually, the hint is unnecessary (with some unnecessary overhead) in this particular case.

Comment: @alfC this turned out to be an interesting question... if tree rebalances itself on every hinted (correctly or not) insert -- does this tree provide "amortized constant" guarantee? (after all rebalancing isn't free) And if it doesn't rebalance -- wouldn't certain insert sequences lead to unbalance tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the underlying implementation of ordered associative containers (which is not specified by the standard, although it is usually a self-balancing binary search tree), the requirements for hinted insert (`iterator insert( const_iterator hint, const value_type& value );`) can be satisfied with the following simple algorithm:

1. Compare value with *hint and *prev(hint)
2. If it fits between them, insert it there.
3. Otherwise, ignore the hint.

As long as `prev(hint)` is amortized constant time, that algorithm is amortized constant time providing that `hint` was correct. ("Correct" in the sense that it is the position just after the insertion point.)

It is perfectly acceptable to ignore the hint if it is incorrect, so providing an incorrect hint does not result in any difference to the datastructure; it is still as balanced (logarithmically accessible) as it was before the insert. But providing an incorrect hint forces the computation of O(1) extra comparisons, so the hinted version of insert should only be used if the hint is usually correct, for some value of "usually".

A common use case is when a search has already been made for the entry to be inserted, so that the insertion position is definitely known. This avoids the overhead of searching twice when something needs to be done prior to the insert, without sacrificing safety in the event that some other process modified the `set` between the `find()` and hinted `insert()` (assuming appropriate locking, of course).

Comment: @Caleth: yup. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about O(1)? I expected it to be O(log n), as in case of non-hinted insert. Also, this doesn't really answer original question

Comment: @c.m.: it's amortized constant time if hint is correct (i.e. it is the position just after the insertion point.) I though that was clear but I added more words to underline the point. Your original question was "does providing a hint cause the tree to be unbalanced" and I state "it is still as balanced (logarithmically accessible) as it was before the insert." That seemed like an answer to me :) If it's not explicit enough, let me know why.

Comment: did you mean "providing incorrect hint lead to O(1) comparisons in addition to O(log n) required to perform normal insert"?

Comment: @C.M.: No. O(log n + 1) is the same as O(log n). Furthermore, although `prev` is amortized O(1), it is worst-case O(log n) so adding it to a full search does not make the full search more than O(log n). Anyway, the point is that once the hint is ignored, it is ignored and has no impact on the future of the tree.

Comment: I know, I am just trying to clarify what you've said to clear confusion. Now, you claim that correctly hinted insert has O(1) complexity and yet keeps tree balanced. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what I claim (except that it is *amortized* O(1) complexity). And that is what the standard requires. The tree may need to be rebalanced after the insert, of course, just as with any other insert. But that is also amortized constant time with an appropriate data structure.

Comment: I would expect tree rebalancing to take more than amortized constant time and to be actually dependent on current tree size. Are you sure about this claim?

Comment: Hmm.. quick search produced [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30501851/red-black-trees-rebalancing?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) which mentions red-black tree rebalance complexity to be O(log N). I'll try to investigate other sources, but if you point me in the right direction it will be appreciated

Comment: In a red-black tree, most of the time rebalancing is constant time and occasionally it requires O(log N) steps. So it is worst-case logarithmic. But if you repeatedly insert into the same tree, you will find that you hit the O(log N) case pretty infrequently; infrequently enough that it is amortized-constant time. It's not strictly constant time, but the standard doesn't require that. I'll see if I can dig up a proof when I get back.

Comment: Actually, I had this one handy: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~fiebrink/423/AmortizedAnalysisExplained_Fiebrink.pdf  See the section on red-black trees on page 12.

Comment: Very good paper. I am stealing it. But this caught my eye: "...amortized cost of any sequence of m insert operations is O(n (to
insert the initial n credits) + m)" -- sounds like the cost to insert 1 element (m = 1) is O(n + 1), where n is the number of elements already in the map. And yet right next to that claim there is another: " the overall amortized cost of a single
insert operation is O(1)". Can you clarify this?

Comment: @c.m.: i think the paper does a pretty good job of explaining that. `n` could be 0; it's the size of the tree when we start the analysis and nothing prevents the tree from being empty. But if it isn't empty, we need some credit to apply to the existing elements in the tree. (I'm using the banker's model here.) When the tree was initially created, it accumulated a cedit of O(n) to reach size n, and so if we're just handed a tree of size n, we need O(n) credits as well to ensure that we always have enough on hand to pay for the next operation.

Comment: Consider the exponential growth algorithm for dynamic arrays, in which we reallocate the array -- which involves copying it -- whenever its size reaches a power of 2. We demonstrate that insertion is amortized constant time: every time we insert an element, we charge two units. These are held by the banker for the moment in which we need to grow the vector. We need to ensure that when the vector reaches size 2^k, we have 2^k credits available to psy for the copy. The next copy will happen at size 2^(k+1), and the 2^k inserts we do will build up a fund of 2*2^k units. So that's fine...

Comment: ... but if we started the analysis with n elements in the array, we will only build up 2*(2^k-n) credits before we hit the first realloc. To "pay" for the n-element tree we need an initial investment of 2n.

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No. The tree will remain balanced, because that's part of the invariant of `std::set`.  Otherwise, it couldn't guarantee logarithmic lookup time (worst case would be linear).

The "hint" is just a hint - not a requirement to "insert it HERE"

Comment: Are you sure it is a part of "`std::set` invariant"? I can't find any such promise in my copy of standard... Or you are referring to red-black tree which is (apparently) most popular modern implementation?

Comment: @C.M. - The requirement ([Table 84](http://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#tab:containers.associative.requirements)) for `a.insert(p, t)` is: "`t` is inserted as close as possible to the position just prior to `p`." It doesn't say *exactly* at `p`.

Comment: @BoPersson how this is relevant to my question? Especially, considering your link says this: "... but amortized constant if t is inserted right before p."

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` and `std::set` are implemented as [Red-Black Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

This means that the longest branch of any subtree is **no more than twice** the size of the smallest branch of that subtree (also applied to root).

You can, therefore, expect your **lookup** operations to take **no longer than twice** the amount of time a perfectly balanced tree would.

Your **insert** and **remove** operations might take a bit longer (as the tree might be rebalanced), but still `O(log n)` (not amortized).

Comment: So, `std::map` implemented as red-black tree gets "balance" guarantee as inherent property of that type of structure? This implies that hinted insert may be more expensive than I thought...

Comment: @C.M. It's pretty much just as good as you can go through. And if the data are helpful (auto-balancing the tree), the balancing steps are very trivial.

Comment: They are not **guaranteed** to be implemented as red-black trees.

Comment: @xskxzr You are right. But C.M. is asking about **most popular implementations**, so I think it qualifies.

Comment: @GillBates Do you know complexity of (correctly) hinted insert operation in red-black tree? Is there any point in using hinted inserts in such `std::map`?

Comment: Ordered associative containers are not required to be auto-balancing treed, but they are guaranteed to have O(log N) find and insert  operations. (Really O(log N). Not expected, average or amortized. ) That's hard to guarantee without an autobalancing tree. But the implementation must guarantee it, in all cases, including hinted insert.

Comment: @rici this doesn't really answer my question, but it raises another one -- how "red-black tree"-based `std::map` can implement "amortized constant if t is inserted right before p" requirement mentioned [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#tab:containers.associative.requirements)?

Comment: @C.M. Had I been trying to answer your question, I would have written an answer :-). Anyway, it's easy to see how to implement that requirement, assuming that you can find the element preceding `p` in amortized constant time (which you can). Just check p and the preceding element, and if the item to be inserted comes between them, put it there.

Comment: @C.M. Ok, I made that an answer. Hope it helps.